# Siebel RESTful API not working on Custom Objects

Tags: rest, siebel

I am trying to test Siebel IP 16 RESTful API from Postman. The Query Operation (GET) is working fine on Vanilla BO's and BC's. Whereas I am not able to perform GET, PUT, POST operations on custom BO's and BC's. On custom BO and BC we have IO as well. I am passing correct BO and BC names in URI.

Below is the URI I am using to update my SR number.

Method: HTTP PUT.

URI: http://SBDEV5:9001/siebel-rest/v1.0/data/LA Service Request IO/Service Request/1-QFLAT 
BO Name is LA Service Request and BC name is Service Request.

Body:

```
{

"Integration Id": "09022016024101940",

"SR Number": "1-44397461",

"Status": "Closed",

"Priority": "High"

}
```

Response

```
{

    "ERROR": "Could not find '<?>' named '<?>'. This object is inactive or nonexistent.(SBL-DAT-00144)"

}
```

Do we need to have any settings for custom objects in Siebel client application while working on Siebel REST API in IP 16? Am I missing anything?

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard and generic error Siebel throws everytime it either does not find an object. It could be a missing field in the business component, or component not found in BO. You will have to raised the server logs for the Integration component on the server and find out what object is missing. The error is not because of REST, even SOAP integrations to this object will throw this error. The fix has to be implemented via Siebel Tools to resolve this error.